# How to generate SSL certificate objective c?

Tags: objective-c, certificate

I am new to iPhone and need to generate certificate for my first app which supports APNS. I went through [this](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services) and [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) site for help and i also am able to create the certificate but as soon as i append the certificate in my application on Xcode it gives me warning like

> "profile doesn't match any valid certificate private key pair in the
>   default keychain"

I was been given a p12 certificate for development but now i am confused whether i need to use the same certificate or need to generate a new one for a new application? I know this question is asked many a time but i am really stuck at the point.

Kindly show me a path. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new certificate request from the keychain tools.  Upload that to the provisioning site and download the resulting certificate.  Remember, the *private key* that corresponds to the certificate is *embedded within* the certificate request, so don't delete it before you export the private key.

Comment: WHat i did is : I installed the p12 certi and then created a new certi from keychain tool using create a certi from certi. authority and uploaded it on apple site and did the whole process many a time,but each time it gives me error like the same.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for the same problem,as i told i already went through all the steps but as per my knowledge what the problem was that the private key given to me was been generated through a windows os and hence was giving some problem. As a solution i deleted the development certificate and created again and solved the issue.Thanks bdares for the help.